# How to import classes defined in __init__.py

Tags: python, package

I am trying to organize some modules for my own use. I have something like this:

```
lib/
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  foo/
    __init__.py
    someobject.py
  bar/
    __init__.py
    somethingelse.py
```

In `lib/__init__.py`, I want to define some classes to be used if I import lib. However, I can't seem to figure it out without separating the classes into files, and import them in`__init__.py`.

Rather than say:

```
    lib/
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      helperclass.py
      foo/
        __init__.py
        someobject.py
      bar/
        __init__.py
        somethingelse.py

from lib.settings import Values
from lib.helperclass import Helper
```

I want something like this:

```
    lib/
      __init__.py  #Helper defined in this file
      settings.py
      foo/
        __init__.py
        someobject.py
      bar/
        __init__.py
        somethingelse.py

from lib.settings import Values
from lib import Helper
```

Is it possible, or do I have to separate the class into another file?

### EDIT

OK, if I import lib from another script, I can access the Helper class. How can I access the Helper class from settings.py?

The example [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) describes Intra-Package References. I quote "submodules often need to refer to each other". In my case, the lib.settings.py needs the Helper and lib.foo.someobject need access to Helper, so where should I define the Helper class?

Comment: Your last example there should work. Are you seeing an ImportError?  Can you paste the details?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

1. '`lib/`'s parent directory must be in `sys.path`.
2. Your '`lib/__init__.py`' might look like this:

   ```
   from . import settings # or just 'import settings' on old Python versions
   class Helper(object):
         pass
   ```

Then the following example should work:

```
from lib.settings import Values
from lib import Helper
```

#### Answer to the edited version of the question:

`__init__.py` defines how your package looks from outside. If you need to use `Helper` in `settings.py` then define `Helper` in a different file e.g., '`lib/helper.py`'.

```
.
|   `-- import_submodule.py
    `-- lib
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- foo
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- someobject.py
    |-- helper.py
    `-- settings.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

The command:

```
$ python import_submodule.py
```

Output:

```
settings
helper
Helper in lib.settings
someobject
Helper in lib.foo.someobject

# ./import_submodule.py
import fnmatch, os
from lib.settings import Values
from lib import Helper

print
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.py'):
        print "# %s/%s" % (os.path.basename(root), f)
        print open(os.path.join(root, f)).read()
        print


# lib/helper.py
print 'helper'
class Helper(object):
    def __init__(self, module_name):
        print "Helper in", module_name


# lib/settings.py
print "settings"
import helper

class Values(object):
    pass

helper.Helper(__name__)


# lib/__init__.py
#from __future__ import absolute_import
import settings, foo.someobject, helper

Helper = helper.Helper


# foo/someobject.py
print "someobject"
from .. import helper

helper.Helper(__name__)


# foo/__init__.py
import someobject
```

Comment: How could I import the Helper class in the settings.py file in my example?

Comment: I don't understand why that's circular. If settings.py needs Helper and say foo.someobject.py needs Helper, where do you suggest I define it?

Comment: wow, the word "helper" really starts to loose meaning in that example. However, you've shown me what I was looking for.

Comment: upvoted for "\_\_init\_\_.py defines how your package looks from outside."

Answer (score 31):

If `lib/__init__.py` defines the Helper class then in settings.py you can use:

```
from . import Helper
```

This works because . is the current directory, and acts as a synonym for the lib package from the point of view of the settings module. Note that it is not necessary to export Helper via `__all__`.

(Confirmed with python 2.7.10, running on Windows.)

Comment: This is working fine for me, downvoters please explain your displeasure?

Answer (score 9):

You just put them in __init__.py.

So with test/classes.py being:

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass
```

... and test/__init__.py being:

```
from classes import *

class Helper(object): pass
```

You can import test and have access to A, B and Helper

```
>>> import test
>>> test.A
<class 'test.classes.A'>
>>> test.B
<class 'test.classes.B'>
>>> test.Helper
<class 'test.Helper'>
```

Comment: Where are you doing the import from?

Comment: Say I want to import Helper from lib/settings.py?

Comment: That will almost certainly result in a circular import (settings will import test and test will import settings)... which will produce the NameError you describe. If you want helpers that are used inside the package you should define an internal module that your code uses.

Comment: Helpers in __init__.py should be for external users to simplify your API.

Comment: External users have no use for Helper. Let's say the Helper class is a wrapper around a sql connection, and the other classes want to use it. I put it in the top most part of the tree thinking all sub-modules would have access.

Comment: If it's not part of the API, then __init__.py really isn't the place for it. lib/internal.py or similar would be much better (which has the double purpose of reducing the likelihood of circular imports).

Answer (score 6):

Add something like this to `lib/__init__.py`

`from .helperclass import Helper`

now you can import it directly:

`from lib import Helper`

Answer (score 4):

Edit, since i misunderstood the question:

Just put the `Helper` class in `__init__.py`.  Thats perfectly pythonic.  It just feels strange coming from languages like Java.

Comment: You misunderstood. I want to eliminate the helperClass.py file if possible.

Comment: Richard isn't the only one who misunderstood.  Your example should be working.  What is the traceback?

Comment: Well, then I read the docs correctly. So, now I just made a test case and it works fine.

Comment: I have the same setup in my package, but I'm getting an ImportError "cannot import name Helper"

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm trying to import the Helper class from settings.py, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You might also want to define `__all__` in `__init__.py` files. It's a list of modules that will be imported when you do

```
from lib import *
```

Answer (score -11):

Maybe this could work:

```
import __init__ as lib
```