# Why it failed without import in python

Tags: python, import, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I am a newbie and am just starting to learn Python programming:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the above code, every is OK. But when I run the code below, it fails with the following error message: **app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QtWidgets'**

```
import sys
import PyQt5
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = PyQt5.Qtwidgets.QmainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

By the way, my Python version is 2.7, I'm using Qt5 library and my operating system is OpenSUSE 13.2, of course, a distribution of Linux.

Comment: `QtWidgets` is a class defined in `__init__.py` of `PyQt5`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py

Comment: I've just read the post you sent. But still confused, would you like to explain  clearly? Thanks. @Selcuk

Answer (score 1):

The `Qtwidgets` file is a compiled `.so` file  in the `PyQt5` directory, as are all the modules, there are no imports in the `__init__.py` file so you need to use from ...

An example using a cython compiled file `test1.cpython-34m.so` in a directory  `py3` with an empty `__init.__py` exhibits the same behaviour:

```
In [1]: import py3

In [2]: py3.test1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9aa45b2a49b6> in <module>()
----> 1 py3.test1

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test1'

In [3]: from py3 import test1
In [4]: test1.foo()
Out[4]: 100
```

The files in PyQt5 are as below:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5$ ls
__init__.py
__pycache__
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtCore.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Qt.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtDBus.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtDesigner.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtGui.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtHelp.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtNetwork.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtOpenGL.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtPrintSupport.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtTest.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtWidgets.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
uic
```

Using `cat` you can see that there are no imports in `__init__.py`:

```
$:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5$ cat __init__.py 
# Copyright (c) 2014 Riverbank Computing Limited <info@riverbankcomputing.com>
# 
# This file is part of PyQt5.
# 
# This file may be used under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# version 3.0 as published by the Free Software Foundation and appearing in
# the file LICENSE included in the packaging of this file.  Please review the
# following information to ensure the GNU General Public License version 3.0
# requirements will be met: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
# 
# If you do not wish to use this file under the terms of the GPL version 3.0
# then you may purchase a commercial license.  For more information contact
# info@riverbankcomputing.com.
# 
# This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE
# WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

So because there are no imports in the `__init__.py`  when you try to  use `PyQt5.Qtwidgets` you get the error you see as the module obviously has no attributes.

If you added  something like `from . import QtWidgets` to the `__init__.py` you could then use `import PyQt5 PyQt5.Qtwidgets` or `PyQt5.Qtwidgets` would also work with a blank init as you are importing the module `Qtwidgets` from the **package** `PyQt5`.

You can see when you `import PyQt5` you then you actually have a module:

```
In [6]: import PyQt5

In [7]: type(PyQt5)
Out[7]: module
```

So the real difference and why you see the output you do is you are trying to import from a **module** in the second  example and a **package** in the first.

Comment: Oh, I see. But if first I `import PyQt5.QWidgets`, then `window = QWidgets.QMainWindow()`, what will happen? I'm in the street now. Maybe I can do the experiment when I at home. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would  need to use PyQt5.QWidgets.QMainWindow()

Answer (score 1):

The `PyQt5` part just provides a namespace for a group of modules. It doesn't contain anything itself, and so you cannot import anything directly from it.

This is a deliberate design decision, and is done for a good reason. There could be a total of thirty or more modules in the package, so it would be a heavy up-front cost to load them **all** every time `PyQt5` itself was imported. So instead, the intention is to only pay the cost of loading the modules you actually need.

However, there may be times when you **do** want to load all the modules at once. For instance, it would be very convenient to be able to do this when experimenting in a python interactive session. And in fact, PyQt provides a special module that does exactly that:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import Qt
>>> Qt.QWidget
<class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget'>
>>> Qt.QObject
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
>>> Qt.QNetworkCookie
<class 'PyQt5.QtNetwork.QNetworkCookie'>
```