# Python Import class in __init__.py from file in same package

Tags: python, class, import, module, directory

I feel like I should know this, having programmed in Python for as long as I have, but I'm constantly learning new things about the fine lanuaguge. The question I have (which may very well be a duplicate, however I haven't been able to find this same case) is this. I have a file layout like this:

```
websocket/
    __init__.py
    client.py
    server.py
```

How can I import classes that are in the file `__init__.py` from `client.py` or `server.py`? Nice and simple :P Thanks in advance! My question isn't a duplicate of [this](/questions/582723) because I am importing from inside the package, and at any rate, doing what the people did in the answer did not help at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import classes defined in \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py)

Comment: doesn't 'import client' work  in the __init__.py

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I want to import a class in __init__.py from client.py

Comment: oh right - my question would then be - why define a class in the '__init__.py' file - i am not convinced that is ever a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names defined in a package `__init__.py` file are available as names in the package namespace itself.

Therefore, if you have a `Connection` class in your `__init__` package, from inside the package you do import it the same way one making use of your package would: refer to it by the package name as in

```
from websocket import Connection
```

If for some reason your package is not configured in your pythonpath, or your directory name can change you can use a relative import - in that case, refer to the current package just as `.` that means that in your `client.py` you can just do:

```
from . import Connection
```

Comment: Thanks, I know what the problem was. I was trying to run `client.py` as the main file, and that didn't sit well with the interpreter for some reason.