# Import from the package from within the package

Tags: python, flask, import, package

This question is similar to the following questions:

1. [python import class in init.py from file in same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128333/python-import-class-in-init-py-from-file-in-same-package/49879338#49879338)
2. [how to import classes defined in init.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py)

However, the solutions there did not work for me.

At runtime I always get the following error:

```
 ImportError: no module named 'project'
```

My project directory is simple

```
project\
   - project\
   -   __init__.py
   -   views.py
   -   modules.py
```

When I try to import from the init.py file

I use

```
from . import app
```

or

```
from project import app
```

I am getting the error I stated above.

I can't seem to figure it out. please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

After davidism advice, this is what i did, just incase someone else have this issue.

I created a file called manage.py in the top directory, just as shown below.

```
project\
   - **manage.py**
   - project\
       -   __init__.py
       -   views.py
       -   modules.py
```

In manage.py i imported my app instance defined in my config.py and run

```
 # manage.py file
 --------------------------------

 from project.config import app

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then you finish off by running the manage.py file

```
projectslocation\project>python3 manage.py
```

Everything works!!!