# Unable to import models in __init__.py django 1.9.4

Tags: django, django-models

My directory structure is.

```
Mypack:
  --> __init__.py
  --> admin.py
  --> apps.py
  --> foo.py
  --> models.py
```

In apps.py, I have AppConfig. I have some methods in foo.py which uses the models imported from models.py. and I imported all methods in **init**.py.

```
from foo import *
```

I make this app installable with pip. when I install it in other django app and try to run python manage.py check. it gives the following error.

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

please suggest me, how to fix this issue?

Comment: I imported my models with " from models import * "

Comment: show your `apps.py`, `__init__.py` / file where you imported foo

Comment: __init__.py:  default_app_config = 'Mypack.apps.myConfig'  from foo import *

Comment: apps.py:  from django.apps import AppConfig

class myConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mypack'
    verbose_name = "django mypack"

Comment: you cannot import models until the application is ready. why are you importing it in `__init__.py` file? do you want to access foo methods directly from package?

Comment: yes.. is there any possibility to import models in __init__.py to make all of my methods accessible from the package

Comment: Importing through `__init__.py` files can be a little tricky, butI think the answer you're looking for would be to follow the formula used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/583065/1842146).

Answer (score 4):

From the [1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9) (emphasis mine):

> - All models need to be defined inside an installed application or
>     declare an explicit app_label. Furthermore, it isn’t possible to
>     import them before their application is loaded. **In particular, it
>     isn’t possible to import models inside the root package of an
>     application.**

You are (indirectly) importing your models into the root package of your app, `Mypack/__init__.py`. If you still want to import the functions in `foo.py` into your root package, you need to make sure that it doesn't import the models when the module is first imported. One option is to use inline imports:

```
def foo():
    from .models import MyModel
    MyModel.objects.do_something()
```

If importing the functions in your root package is not a hard requirement (e.g. for backwards compatibility), I would personally just stop importing them in `__init__.py` and change other imports to use `Mypack.foo`.