# Cannot import from __init__ in a subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

This is my folder structure:

```
storage/
    __init__.py - contains class StorageAbstract, class DummyStorage, class STORE_TYPE
    file.py - contains class FileStorage
    db/
        __init__.py - contains class DbStorage, class DbStorageAbstract 
        pg.py - contains class PgStorage
        sqlite.py - contains class SQLiteStorage
```

Classes PgStorage and SQLiteStorage inherit from DbStorageAbstract so I need to import it. I do it like this (in pg.py and sqlite.py) :

```
from . import DbStorageAbstract
```

And that throws the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DbStorageAbstract'
```

However, when I move DbStorageAbstract from storage/db/__init__py. to storage/__init__py and import it like this:

```
from .. import DbStorageAbstract
```

then it works fine. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and many other resources but still can't figure out what is causing the problem. If it was circular dependence then moving the class to another file would not help I think.

If there is any more information needed, let me know in the comments and I will edit the question.

I am using Python 3.5

**EDIT:**

Although this question has been identified as a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) I don't see how it answers my question. Unlike the other question, I already have **init** files in each folder. If I am wrong please point me to where I can find the answer.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the db/**init**.py file:

```
##################################################################
# Copyright 2018 Open Source Geospatial Foundation and others    #
# licensed under MIT, Please consult LICENSE.txt for details     #
##################################################################

#import sys
#sys.path.append("/mnt/c/Users/Jan/Documents/GitHub/pywps")

import logging
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from pywps import configuration as config
from .. import StorageAbstract
from . import sqlite
from . import pg


LOGGER = logging.getLogger('PYWPS')


class DbStorageAbstract(StorageAbstract):
    """Database storage abstract class
    """

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def store(self, output):

        pass


    @abstractmethod
    def store_output(self, file_name, identifier):

        pass


class DbStorage(StorageAbstract):

    def __init__(self):

       self.storage = self.get_db_type()


    def store(self, output):

        assert(self.storage is not None)
        self.storage.store(output)


    def get_db_type(self):
        # get db_type from configuration 
        try:
            db_type = config.get_config_value('db', 'db_type')
        except KeyError:
            raise exception("Database type has not been specified")

        # create an instance of the appropriate class
        if db_type == "PG":
            storage = pg.PgStorage()
        elif db_type == "SQLITE":
            storage = sqlite.SQLiteStorage()
        else:
            raise exception("Unknown database type: '{}'".format(db_type))

        return storage
```

Answer (score 3):

Imports happens before class definition. In `db/__init__.py` you are importing `pg.py, sqlite.py` which are depends on classes defined here. To solve it move `DbStorageAbstract` to another file and if you are going to use it in the same file with `pg.py, sqlite.py` then make sure import is going to be like this:

```
from . import dbstorage # this file is the new one contains DbStorageAbstract class
from . import pg, sqlite
```

Note that if two modules are depends on each other try to create a third module so solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should create another file in your subdirectory

```
storage/
    __init__.py - contains class StorageAbstract, class DummyStorage, class STORE_TYPE
    file.py - contains class FileStorage
    db/
        __init__.py - 
        pg.py - contains class PgStorage
        sqlite.py - contains class SQLiteStorage
        base.py contains class DbStorage, class DbStorageAbstract
```

Then, the `pg.py` file and `sqlite.py` file will import the classes like:

```
from base import DbStorageAbstract
```

And the `__init__.py` file will also look like this

```
from base import DbStorageAbstract,  DbStorageAbstract
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the most pythonic way, probably this might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py

Comment: Yeah, I agree what you suggest would work but I am trying to keep the number of files to minimum so creating another file is exactly what I don't want to do (unless it is necessary).

Comment: Could you not use the full path to import then? from storage.db import DbStorageAbstract should work