# python : importing from parent __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, import, python-import

I have defined a method `foo` and a class `bar` that has a method `foo_bar` in `__init__.py` file

```
dir/
   __init__.py
   runme.py
```

Now I want to import `__init__.py` from `runme.py`

I have tried

```py
# in runme.py

from . import foo

foo()
```

and

```py
import foo

foo()
```

But neither works. I'm using Python 3.7 and Windows 10 Home

I have read [How to import classes defined in __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py) and done some research.

Python's exception is:

```py
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

```py
# __ init __.py 

def foo():
   print("Im Foo") 
class bar:
    def __init__():
        pass
    def foo_bar(self):
        print("Im Foo_Bar in class bar")
```

Comment: Other options are available if its not possible i will change the file

Comment: `dir` is a built-in function, so it's a bad idea to name a package or a module `dir`.

Comment: it is an example name the name is diffrent in my computer

Comment: You should use CamelCase for class names, so `class bar` becomes `class Bar`. See https://pep8.org/#class-names

Comment: oh god they are example ONLY EXAMPLE

Comment: there is no bar or Bar class in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pkg` is your main packages, you can import it (aka the `pkg/__init__.py` file) doing:

```py
import pkg
```

If you want the `foo_bar` function in this package, you can write:

```py
from pkg import foo_bar
```

So, in `runme.py` module, you can do:

```py
from pkg import foo_bar

foo_bar(...)
```

Of course, you need to call your `runme.py` module from the root directory (the parent of `pkg` directory):

```sh
python pkg/runme.py
# or
python -m pkg.runme
```

Please, consider reading [Executing modules as scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

**EDIT 1**

You can add your project root directory to `sys.path`:

```py
# in `runme.py`:
def _fix_sys_path():
    import os
    import sys

    HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # /path/to/project_dir/pkg
    PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(HERE)  # /path/to/project_dir
    sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)


_fix_sys_path()
from pkg import foo_bar

foo_bar(...)
```

Comment: it is going to be a pip package in that case does it work ???

Comment: `pip` is a tool used to install Python packages, not to create it. Consider reading [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#packaging-python-projects)

Comment: i know all these . i have 3 packages . it is going to be an update for one

Comment: i sayd because  i cant tell the client to go back a level and run it

Comment: if anyone need more information about the problem only say i will add more information

Comment: You can add your project root directory to `sys.path`, see EDIT 1

Comment: is your updated answer going to work when a client installs it with pip

Comment: thanks i tested it it works for i in range(1, 1000):print("Hurray!!!!"

Comment: someone close it i got my answer