# How to import the codes in __init__.py

Tags: python, package, sys

Assume I have the following file structure:

```
A/
   __init__.py
   B.py
```

Inside `__init.py__` I have the following:

```
__init__.py/
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Then inside the B.py I have the following:

```
B.py/
    from A import np
    print(np.linspace(0,10,10))
```

However, this code produces an `error that no module named A`. If for now, we do not consider the circular import problem which is not the case here. How can I import from

```
__init.py__
```

Since otherwise, all the imports I have in it will be useless. I recall a while ago I could run a code like above with no problem but now this is a problem.

I can just add the path to package A to `sys.path` but then every time I should run the command and is not even scalable or practical.

Does anyone why python is complaining and how I can import what I have in **init**.py?

Comment: Why is B inside the A folder? Just move it into the parent directory

Comment: No B is actually a script inside the package. If it is outside I have no problem. Just want to use the codes inside __init__.py in B. When writing from A import np this will run the __init__.py. This should work fine. This is why we place all the imports in __init__.py

Comment: Oh, well you can use `from . import np` in B and then in your main.py file elsewhere to run the code in B, you'd just use `import A.B` (or `importlib.reload(A.B)` if running it multiple times). If you want to run B standalone I can't understand why you'd want it as apart of the package though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import classes defined in \_\_init\_\_.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582723/how-to-import-classes-defined-in-init-py)